# Blacklisting client IP addresses with haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way of specifying a list of IP addresses to block in HaProxy, preferably read from an external file (rather than embedded in the config)?  I've seen a solution using ACLs, but it doesn't seem very maintainable to me.

Answer (score 2):

While that may in theory be possible, it's the wrong place to do it. Instead of trying to make your loadbalancer smarter than it should be, you should really use the firewall in your OS or a network firewall instead.

Comment: I see, right. Perhaps iptables would be the place to do it then?

Comment: If you're using linux, then yes, iptables would be the place to go.

Comment: Iptables is definitely the way to go. We use a 'sub-chain' in the filter table that we can flush and re-add to for individual ip blocking